# Difference between java -server and ngen in c#

Tags: c#, java, jit, ngen

What would you say are the key differences when comparing Java running a jar with the -server flag and a .net assembly that has been run through ngen.exe  It seems like they are trying to do the same thing for the different run-times.

Answer (score 2):

The key differences are that ngen compiles to native code, whereas "java -server" affects how the JVM runs. It's roughly equivalent to the [key differences between apples and oranges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges).